# How can I reinstall the sash in my window?

Tags: windows

First let me just say sorry in advance if I use the wrong terminology. The bottom sash is no longer attached to the side pulleys. On the bottom of the sash I'm able to unscrew the little pegs that fit into the side pulleys. I don't think the pulleys are broken, but I'm having a hard time trying to get the sash back onto them.

I was messing with it when I first moved into this house cause I never had this type of window before. I thought I could remove the sash cause I realized the top portion folded forward and out of the frame, so i tugged on it and the pulley/spring zoomed up. The sash is now completely able to be removed from the frame. I admit it was stupid of me to mess with something I didn't understand.

The pin hole part can come out. The balances are attached to cords and still have tension. I don't think anything's broken. I think it's just a matter of how do I get the pins in the holes while it's all in the window frame.

The pulleys do not have a little peg that comes out from the sides of the window frame itself to keep them lowered at all, and they require a lot of force with a screwdriver to lower them down. Any advice on how to get the sash back on the pulleys? Or is a part broken?

The pegs at the bottom of my sash would fit into the pulley's hole (in the picture).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Reinstall the socket component into the spring trolley. It's unclear to me how it engages the trolley, but you may need to rotate the inner part to retract the ears.
2. Holding the sash level (with the glass horizontal), insert one sash pin into its socket. If the two sockets are close to level, do this, then raise or lower the engaged side slightly to offset it from the other side.
3. Insert the opposite side, moving the original side up or down as needed to adjust the distance between them. Once it's engaged, set the sash edge level. The sash should now be supported at the bottom edge, with the top edge toward the interior.
4. Swing the sash top up into position. It should snap into the track with the spring latches we see at the bottom of the second photo.